# Would like to connect to different On-premise S3 compatible storages in the same

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

Currently we are connecting to our teams's bucket in our on-premise S3 compatible storage.

**Configuration class:**

```
@Configuration
public class S3Config {

@Value("${aws.access_key_id}")
private String awsId;
@Value("${aws.secret_access_key}")
private String awsKey;
@Value("${s3.endpoint}")
private String endpoint;

@Value("${s3.keystorePD}")
private String keystorePD;

@Value("${s3.jksFile}")
private String jksFile;


private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(S3Config.class);
@PostConstruct
public void init()
{

    log.info("Initializing SSL Configuration for S3 bucket");
    System.setProperty(ApplicationConstants.KEY_STORE_TYPE,"jks");
    System.setProperty(ApplicationConstants.TRUST_STORE_TYPE,"jks");
    System.setProperty(ApplicationConstants.KEY_STORE_PROPERTY,Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(jksFile).getFile());
    System.setProperty(ApplicationConstants.TRUST_STORE_PROPERTY,Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(jksFile).getFile());
    System.setProperty(ApplicationConstants.KEY_STORE_PD,keystorePD);
    System.setProperty(ApplicationConstants.TRUST_STORE_PD,keystorePD);
    log.info("Successfully initialized SSL Configuration for S3 bucket");
}

@Bean
public AmazonS3 s3client() {
    log.info("Initializing the S3 client");
    AmazonS3 s3Client = null;
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsId,
            awsKey);
    s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCreds);
    s3Client.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    return s3Client;
}
```

Usage :

```
@Autowired
AmazonS3 s3Client;

public void uploadFile(File file, String targetLocation, String bucketName) {
    log.info("converted file size : " + file.getTotalSpace());
    log.info("bucketName : " + bucketName);
    log.info("targetLocation : " + targetLocation);
    s3Client.putObject(bucketName, targetLocation, file);
}
```

My requirement is to create the client dynamically for each incoming request. So that lets say if team A is passed, s3 configuration with team A's jks file are used to connect to the storage.

I am using :

- Spring Boot v2.3.1.RELEASE
- aws-sdk v1.11.560
- Open JDK v11.0.1

How do I achieve this ?

**UPDATE:**

**I will have the jks files, access_keys, access_ids with me from the start of the application.**

Comment: Can you load the teams' jks files at startup time? Or only when the request comes in?

Comment: @marc yes, I will be having the jks files and creds with me from the start. I have updated the same in the question.

Comment: Ok, then you can configure a s3Client for each team. You might have a S3ConfigTeamA class to configure the s3ClientTeamA and so on. But I am not sure if the env variables you are setting will conflict.

Answer (score 0):

There are two unique problems in this situation

1. Using non system properties for supplying encryption material
2. Switching (and building if needed) credentials for each request.

Following solution outline will solve both the problems. It uses StaticEncryptionMaterialsProvider instead to avoid dependency on system properties. to solve second problem, the S3ClientResolver uses a REQUEST scope with proxyMode as TARGET_CLASS to ensure wiring in spring context works as it should in this case.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "teams")
@Component
public class CredentialsMap extends HashMap<String, S3Credentials> {
    // key will be team name and value will have s3Credentials
}

public class S3Credentials {
    private String awsId;
    private String awsKey;
    private String endpoint;
    private String keystorePD;
    private String jksFile;
    /* Add all getter and setters as well */
}

/**
 * Building client is an expensive operation. This provider lazily builds the clients
 * and cache them using Map for subsequent usage without incurring built cost agian.
 */
public class S3ClientProvider {
    @Autowired
    private CredentialsMap credentialsMap;

    private Map<String, AmazonS3> clients;

    public AmazonS3 getClient(String client) {
        if (!clients.containsKey(client))
            clients.put(client, buildClient(client));
        return clients.get(client);
    }

    private AmazonS3 buildClient(String client) {
        S3Credentials cred = credentialsMap.get(client);
        // TODO - add try/catch
        KeyPair kp = getKeyPair(cred);

        AWSStaticCredentialsProvider cp = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(
                cred.getAwsId(), cred.getAwsKey()));

        AmazonS3 as3 = AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
                .withCredentials(cp)
                .withCryptoConfiguration(new CryptoConfiguration(CryptoMode.AuthenticatedEncryption))
                .withEncryptionMaterials(new StaticEncryptionMaterialsProvider(new EncryptionMaterials(kp)))
                .build();
        as3.setEndpoint(cred.getEndpoint());
        return as3;
    }

    private KeyPair getKeyPair(S3Credentials cred) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResource(cred.getJksFile()).getFile());

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        keystore.load(is, cred.getKeystorePD().toCharArray());

        // the only key in your JKS must have this alias
        // you may also add the alias as another property in your configuration instead
        String alias = "myS3Key";

        Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, cred.getKeystorePD().toCharArray());
        if (key instanceof PrivateKey) {
            Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
            PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
            return new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) key);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid key");
    }
}

@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class S3ClientResolver {

    /* You can inject current request OR any other bean for that matter here */
    /* Spring authenticaiotn object to get access to current logged in user */
    @Autowired
    private Authentication authentication;

    @Autowired
    private S3ClientProvider provider;

    public AmazonS3 getClient() {
        // deduce client value from current authenticaiotn object as may be applicable
        String client = "TODO";
        return provider.getClient(client);
    }
}
```

The configuration for different clients can be specified in spring boot's application.yml like following

```
teams:
  one:
    awsId: abc
    awsKey: abc
    endpoint: https://example.com
    keystorePD: onejskpass
    jksFile: one.jks
  two:
    awsId: abc2
    awsKey: abc2
    endpoint: https://example.com
    keystorePD: twojskpass
    jksFile: two.jks
```

With this in place, your code will look like following

```
@Autowired
private S3ClientResolver resolver;

public void uploadFile(File file, String targetLocation, String bucketName) {
    log.info("converted file size : " + file.getTotalSpace());
    log.info("bucketName : " + bucketName);
    log.info("targetLocation : " + targetLocation);
    resolver.getClient().putObject(bucketName, targetLocation, file);
}
```

Please adjust it as per your own environments. I quickly pulled up these pieces from one of my similar work in past. I have left many items in above snippet as comments. Please go through and adjust accordingly for your use cases.

[Edit - July 15, 2020]

jackfr0st, the keypair generation logic is working, I just verified it with following stand alone program which is exact replica of what's mentioned above with correction of return statement (which was missing earlier) in line `new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) key)` - for this purpose I generated a fresh keystore (testjks.jks) using following command - `keytool -genkey -alias mydomain -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks  -keysize 2048`

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

public class ExtractKeypair {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
        KeyPair kp = generateKeypair("testjks.jks");
    }

    public static KeyPair generateKeypair(String file) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResource(file).getFile());
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
        keystore.load(is, "password".toCharArray());

        // the only key in your JKS must have this alias
        // you may also add the alias as another property in your configuration instead
        String alias = "mydomain";

        Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, "password".toCharArray());
        if (key instanceof PrivateKey) {
            Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
            PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
            return new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) key);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid key");
    }
}
```

If you are still facing problem, I'll suggest to look at resource returned (`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(file).getFile()`) as that's the only variable which can cause the problem if not correct. I tested above program with oracle jdk 8.

Comment: thank you for this. I am however facing one issue whilst fetching the key pair from the keystore I am getting null. 

 String alias = cred.getAlias();
 Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, cred.getKeystorePD().toCharArray());

any idea on this ? I am using bouncycastle

Comment: Just verified and updated my answer with a standalone working program to extract keypair. Please verify the resource if it's still not working for you.

Comment: Pls also verify the alias if it's correct or not, that's more likely to result into null Key object. As per [KeyStore.getKey() javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#getKey-java.lang.String-char:A-) this method will return "_the requested key, or null if the given alias does not exist or does not identify a key-related entry_"